# Problem reading x & y co-ordinates of tweened object on enter frame - AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Hi Can someone please explain why the lines drawn between the circles in the code below are not aligned with the centre of the circles?

It seems the x and y properties of the circles are not up to date with their actual positions but how can this be?

```
import flash.display.Sprite
import fl.transitions.*;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

var mcs=[];

function go(Y,size,col,opac){
    var mc=new Sprite()
    mc.y=Y
    mc.x=600
    mc.graphics.beginFill(col,opac)
    mc.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,size/3)
    mc.graphics.endFill()
    addChild(mc)
    mcs.push(mc)

    var xPosT = new Tween(mc, "x", Strong.easeOut, 600, 0, 3,true);
}

function upd(e){
    graphics.clear()
    graphics.moveTo(mcs[0].x,mcs[0].y)
    for(var i in mcs){
        graphics.lineStyle(0,0xCCCCCC,1)
        graphics.lineTo(mcs[i].x, mcs[i].y)
    }
}

setInterval(function(){
    go(randomNo(400),randomNo(50,5),0xCCCCCC,1)
},500)

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,upd)


//Returns a random number between from and to inclusive
function randomNo(to:Number,from=0,decimalPlaces=0):Number{
    var ret=roundDecimal(Math.random()*(to-from)+from,decimalPlaces)
    return(ret)
}
function roundDecimal(num:Number, precision:int):Number{
    var decimal:Number = Math.pow(10, precision);
    return Math.round(decimal* num) / decimal;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy The tween is updating after the enter frame  event fires.
You should never use the enterframe event to control UI like this.
remove this line completely.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,upd)
```

And add this line in your go function.

```
var xPosT = new Tween(mc, "x", Strong.easeOut, 600, 0, 3,true);
xPosT.addEventListener( TweenEvent.MOTION_CHANGE, upd )
```

MOTION_CHANGE fires after the tween update.
Also note you have to consider garbage collection, because if this app runsfor an extended period it will have issues

Comment: for starters your mcs array will eventually hit the array limits. also all the objects you are adding to the stage and to the mcs array are never removed and just keep piling on top of each other

Comment: When the array size becomes huge looping over it will slow down the app also

Comment: Ah yes sorry its just a chunk of a larger code block. I have them removed from the stage and the array later on. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: As a matter of fact try changing your timer to like 100 miliseconds watch what happens